# Theme in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How do I  change the theme in Jupyter Notebook back?

I changed it some time ago and I regret that now.

Now I want to return the default one but I can't do that because its name is unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the library `jupyter-themes`

```
pip install jupyterthemes 
jt -r
```

Comment: @amateur "Great, it works" is nice to hear. But it's *much* better to mark the suggestion from bigbounty as the accepted answer. That will even earn you **2** reputation points. And when that happens (meaning you'll have **15** points), you'll earn the right to award other posts with your up-votes. And *that* is the proper way to thank someone for their efforts in helping you out